# Java files in a jar file

Tags: java, file, jar

Is there a technical reason for not having the source java files in the jar file?  I came across a service jar that had both the class jars and the source java files in the same jar.  Typical third-party libraries will bundle these different types of files into separate jars.  The binary is necessary for execution and the src.jar file is useful to debug using the exact code that the class files were built with.

To me the reasoning is: it slows down server startup because the additional files need to be decompressed and perhaps indexed.  Are there any other reasons I can use to advocate for abandoning this one-off build process?

Please do not respond that jar files are essentially zip files and anything goes, I am looking for technical reasons during runtime to avoid this situation.  BTW the services using these JARs have been working for a long time, so it is not manifesting any actual perceived defects.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't cause any problems to have source files in the JAR with the binary class files. The main reason to keep them separate is to avoid making JARs bigger than necessary for runtime deployment. As far as I know, the convention of distributing a `-sources` JAR file for open source libraries originated with Maven, which will produce artifacts in this way by default.